# meteor autoform _id field

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have this Schema :

```
Schemas = {};

Schemas.Id = {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    label: 'Id',
    //max: ID_LENGTH,
    defaultValue : Random.id(ID_LENGTH),
    denyUpdate: true
};

Schemas.Name = {
    type: String,
    label: 'Name',
    max: 75
};

Schemas.Description = {
    type: String,
    label: 'Description',
    max: 500,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
        rows: 5
    }
};

//-- Attribute
Schemas.Attribute = {
    _id: Schemas.Id,
    attribute_name : Schemas.Name,
    attribute_description : Schemas.Description
};

Collections.Attributes.attachSchema(Schemas.Attribute);
```

i have a request from client they can insert **`_id`** manually.
but autoform cant permit it,
this the template :

```
<template name="pg_attr_insert">
    {{#autoForm _id="afInsertDemo" type="insert" collection=Collections.Attributes}}
        <div class="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='_id'}}has-error{{/if}}">
            <label class="control-label">{{afFieldLabelText name='_id'}}</label>
            {{> afFieldInput name='_id'}}
            {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='_id'}}
                <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessattribute_description name='_id'}}}</span>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='attribute_name'}}has-error{{/if}}">
            <label class="control-label">{{afFieldLabelText name='attribute_name'}}</label>
            {{> afFieldInput name='attribute_name'}}
            {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='attribute_name'}}
                <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessattribute_description name='attribute_name'}}}</span>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='attribute_description'}}has-error{{/if}}">
            <label class="control-label">{{afFieldLabelText name='attribute_description'}}</label>
            {{> afFieldInput name='attribute_description'}}
            {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='attribute_description'}}
                <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessattribute_description name='attribute_description'}}}</span>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Person</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Form</button>
        </div>
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

this is the error :

> Uncaught Error: Every autoForm and quickForm must have an "id"
>   attribute set to a unique string.

is there anyway autoform permit insert `_id` manually? and how?

Comment: You could create your own ID field that gets displayed and keep the _id field hidden from users.

Comment: i try it, but it didnt work when submit, i mean it getting error and no data inserted

Answer (score 0):

Oke i know my false, i create

```
{{#autoForm _id="afInsertDemo" type="insert" collection=Collections.Attributes}}
```

i just convert it to :

```
{{#autoForm id="afInsertDemo" type="insert" collection=Collections.Attributes}}
```

Comment: Correct. The id that you have defined in the schema is for the unique record ID that will be inserted in the mongo collection. The error message you got is because the form had no ID associated with it. Think of it as ```<form id="formID">``` which in autoform notation is written as ```{{#autoForm id="formID" .... }}```